# PyQt prevent multiple instances of an application popping up the same dialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have an application which pops up a notification dialog to the front of all windows whenever new rss feeds are available. The user can have multiple instances of the application running though, and I only want a single notification dialog to pop up. Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply place a lockfile somewhere to indicate that another process is showing a dialog, and check wheater that exists before displaying another one.

A more sophisticated way would be to use [`QSharedMemory`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsharedmemory.html) to synchronize your access. I've done something similar using a context manager in a comparable situation, but for this case it could look something like:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSharedMemory


class MemoryCondition:
    def __init__(self, key='memory_condition_key'):
        self._shm = QSharedMemory(key)
        if not self._shm.attach():
            if not self._shm.create(1):
                raise RuntimeError('error creating shared memory: %s' %
                                   self._shm.errorString())
        self.condition = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self._shm.lock()
        if self._shm.data()[0] == b'\x00':
            self.condition = True
            self._shm.data()[0] = b'\x01'
        self._shm.unlock()
        return self.condition

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.condition:
            self._shm.lock()
            self._shm.data()[0] = b'\x00'
            self._shm.unlock()


# usage example:
app = QApplication([])

with MemoryCondition() as condition:
    if condition:
        mb = QMessageBox()
        mb.setText("you'll only see one of me")
        mb.exec_()
    else:
        print("other process is doing it's stuff")
```

Comment: How do you call the memory release, just by calling the __exit__ method directly?

Comment: I'm getting self._shm.data()[0]
TypeError: 'sip.voidptr' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: I don't know, it works perfectly for me. Maybe a different Qt version? locking/unlocking is all done automatically by the context manager, when the with block exits the flag in memory is automatically reset to 0.

Comment: I really like your solution, but I can't get it to work. I do get a sip.voidptr option which I'm guessing is a pointer to the memory, but I still don't know how to read the data off it. I was investigating using the ctypes library in some way to do it :( What python version are you using this on? I'm on 2.6.4

Comment: probably you're using a sip version older then version 4.12 (check sip.SIP_VERSION_STR), before that version [`sip.voidptr` didn't support the memoryview api](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#sip.voidptr) and could not be modified directly. The only way i know would be to use ctypes. fortunalely `int(sip.voidptr)` returns it's address, so it's easy, i've pasted a modified version [here](http://pastie.org/7759489)